# Is there a function to search if an index contains a particular string

Tags: sql, plsql

I am new to Pl/SQL and came across an issue. I made a dummy table of some football teams names. I am using a cursor and calling teams where the capacity is greater than 50000 assigning it to the cursor. My issue is after the for loop I do not know how to check if the index contains a certain string ('Man') after which I was to put print a prefix in front of the teams name. e.g. the SELECT block returns "Man United" and "Chelsea". I have searched through google and seen examples of using contains and like and INSTR etc but none work, would someone please help.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_team IS
  SELECT DISTINCT TEAM_NAME
  FROM TEAMS
  WHERE CAP > 50000;

BEGIN
  FOR n_inx IN cur_team LOOP
     IF.....(PART I DONT KNOW)
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Favourite: ' || n_inx);
     ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rival: ' || n_inx);
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

That is what I have so far and I am struggling with the IF statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_team IS
  SELECT DISTINCT TEAM_NAME
  FROM TEAMS
  WHERE CAP > 50000;

BEGIN
  FOR n_inx IN cur_team LOOP
     IF n_inx.team_name LIKE '%Man%'
     THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Favourite: ' || n_inx.team_name);
     ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rival: ' || n_inx.team_name);
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, can I ask what the '%Man%' does, I have seen that syntax when researching but clearly I didn't understand it.

Comment: @hawks The percent sign is a wildcard and stands for one or more characters or no character. In this example, any string can be placed before and after the word "Man". You use it together with the LIKE function.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you! And I also see that I was making the mistake of not specifying the column name when calling calling the index.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify some terms, in this construction:

```
for n_inx in cur_team loop
```

`n_inx` is not an index but a [PL/SQL record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html), implicitly defined based on the columns of `cur_team`. (I think the documentation uses rather confusing wording here.) [Records have *fields*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html). In this case the record has one field, `team_name`, and you can refer to it using dot notation: `n_inx.team_name`. Perhaps a better name for the record would be `r_team`, or just `r`. It's not an index, and there is nothing numeric about it (if that's what the `n_` prefix means).

Also, the procedure [`dbms_output.put_line`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-19FA480D-591E-4584-9650-5D37C4AFA530) accepts a single `varchar2` parameter, not a record, so `dbms_output.put_line(some_record)` will be rejected.

Within PL/SQL programming, [collections (arrays) have indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html). The array index is the key that identifies one element in an array, for example `1` and `2` below, not the text values:

```
myCollection(1) := 'Manchester United';
myCollection(2) := 'Chelsea';
```

(You could also define an associative array of numbers (or anything else) indexed by varchar2, in which case you might have

```
myCollection('Manchester United') := 1;
myCollection('Chelsea') := 2;
```

and then to find the array elements whose index contained 'Man', you would have to loop through it from beginning to end. However, this isn't your situation.)

So to reword your question, you are looking for a way (not necessarily a function) to check for a text pattern within a field of a record. You can break that down into two issues:

1. **How to extract a single field's value from a record:**
   Use `recordname.fieldname`, in your example `n_inx.team_name` (but I'd recommend choosing a different name for the record).
2. **How to match a wildcard or regex pattern in a string value:**
   Use simple wildcards `%` and `_` with [`like` conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html), or more sophisticated regexes with the [`regexp_like` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19).

Comment: Thank you for the tips and clarification, I will need to look at the documentation in greater detail to make sure I am coding it efficiently and in the correct form.